# Android force to standard keyboard

Tags: android, keyboard, android-edittext

I am writing a spelling quiz app. I want the EditText where the user will enter their guess to not provide any spelling hints or suggested words. I have the

```
 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|textPhonetic"
```

set, but I have seen that with some keyboards (touchpal for one), you still get word hints. Btw, I also tried it without the textPhonetic--same result. On the other hand, it looks like the standard default keyboard does follow the inputType. Is there a way to force the app/editText to use the default keyboard? If not, is there a way to tell pragmatically if a user has set the keyboard to something non-standard? Or is there a way to tell if a particular user's keyboard will honor the textNoSuggestions setting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to force the app/editText to use the default keyboard?

No. Moreover, there is no single "default" keyboard in Android -- that can and does differ by device.

> If not, is there a way to tell pragmatically if a user has set the keyboard to something non-standard?

I don't think that there will be a reliable way to do this. Bear in mind that the user can not only change their default keyboard to be some third-party app, but that they can also change input methods on the fly.

> Or is there a way to tell if a particular user's keyboard will honor the textNoSuggestions setting?

No, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could implement your own in-app input solution like the various logo quiz apps do, for example. You could basically create your own custom keyboard within the app. See the answers here for more detail: [Custom 'Keyboard' built in an application on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196511/android-custom-keyboard-built-in-an-application)

Answer (score 0):

Setting input type to "visiblePassword" works where "textNoSuggestions" does not for keyboards like swyft of fleksy.