# Android: Create system-wide custom keyboards, like iOS8 extension keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, custom-controls

Starting with `iOS8`, Apple offers the possibility to [create custom keyboards](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Keyboard.html). These keyboards have to be activated in the settings (like the emoji keyboard for example).

I know you can create custom keyboards for your own application ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196511/android-custom-keyboard-built-in-an-application)), but this keyboard is not available in other applications like `GMail`.

Is there a way to accomplish this task? Or is this not possible at all?

**EDIT** 
Or better question, is it possible to extend the custom keyboard with new words/symbols. In iOS, you simply get a new keyboard view with new symbols.

Comment: it is possible? Yes, it's been possible for 5 years now, since Android 1.5. And if you want to create your own keyboard you have to create it yourself.

Comment: @Budius I did not ask to create my own keyboard, I was asking if it's possible to extend them..comparing to the ios way

Comment: no, it's not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to accomplish this task?

Yes. It has been possible for several years on Android to create [custom input method editors](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html).

Comment: That's true, but the docs say `only one IME may be enabled at a time.` I'm looking for a way to extend the already existing keyboard, if possible... I clarified my answer

Comment: @longilong: "I'm looking for a way to extend the already existing keyboard, if possible" -- that is definitely not possible.