# Change keyboard language programmatically

Tags: android

In my application the user selects a language and I want to show the selected language when the keyboard opens (if it is present in the keyboard options). The keyboard provides that option, so it should be possible.

Comment: What did you try with this provided option ?

Comment: When the keyboard opens you can long press the spacebar and choose a language

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a big work around about how to do this - which is create your own keyboard, and to do this you'll have to know the keyboards you're aiming for. (which will be exact duplicate of the regular keyboard)

General guide on the subject [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) & [code samples](https://developer.android.com/samples/index.html).

[Create a custom keyboard View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196511/custom-keyboard-built-in-an-application-on-android) which extends keyboardView
 
In it create static key value variable like

```
static final int KEYCODE_LANGUAGE_SWITCH_ENG = -102;
static final int KEYCODE_LANGUAGE_SWITCH_URDU = -103;
```

after that in your IME class where you have implemented the inputMethodService, create the keyboards inside the onInitializeInterface override function. like

```
mSymbolsKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty2);
mEngQwertyKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.eng_qwerty);
```

after this add these final static keys in the onKey override function as switch cases, and in the cases set the keyboards accordingly:

```
setKeyboard(mEngQwertyKeyboard);
```

Comment: I have seen this answer but still could not use it properly, could you please provide some details?

Comment: Elaborated my answer @Belzebub

Comment: I know this answer is what I'm looking for but I still struggle to apply it. Is it possible to have a bit more details/explanations ?

Answer (score 3):

since api 24+ you can use `Locale`

```
mEditText.setImeHintLocales(new LocaleList(new Locale("en", "USA")));
```

Answer (score 1):

this code is working fine

```
public class ParisaKeyboard extends InputMethodService implements KeyboardView.OnKeyboardActionListener {

public KeyboardView kv;
private Keyboard keyboard;
private Keyboard persianKeyboard;

@Override
public View onCreateInputView() {

    kv = (KeyboardView)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.keyboard,null);

    keyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.qwerty);
    persianKeyboard = new Keyboard(this, R.xml.persian);

    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
    kv.setOnKeyboardActionListener(this);
    return kv;
}

@Override
public void swipeLeft() {

    kv.setKeyboard(persianKeyboard);
}

@Override
public void swipeRight() {
    kv.setKeyboard(keyboard);
}
```

so you can change language by swiping to left and right .