# Change the Default Keyboard Input Language in android application

Tags: java, android, node.js, localization

I have android application in which i need to allow the user to change the input Language shown in the default keyboard, upon request or by default, for example, i may prompt the user at the beginning to select the default language and after that, whenever the default keyboard is used, the app always displays the Language of the keyboard the selected language?

Comment: what do you need exactly and what have you tried so far ?

Comment: I need to allow the user to change the input Language of keyboard as shown in the default keyboard, upon request or by default after that, app always displays the Language of the keyboard that are being selected.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12303593/change-keyboard-input-language   and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569922/change-keyboard-language-programatically