# Changing input keyboard language with locale

Tags: android, keyboard, android-configchanges

I have an Android application in which I have given an option for the users to select the language. In my app I have given Hindi and English language when the user selects the language Hindi it shows the Hindi strings perfectly.

But what I want to do is when the user selects Hindi language the input type (keyboard) should also changes to Hindi. I can use custom keyboard inside my Android app.

Comment: you may look into this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569922/change-keyboard-language-programatically