# android - Set keyboard language input programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, keyboard

My app supports en and ar language. If the phone language is english but the app language is arabic, I want the keyboard input to be arabic. Is that possbile? By default the keyboard input is tied to the phone language and not the app locale.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38569922/change-keyboard-language-programmatically